# Matrix-vector multiplication: simple case

Tags: matrices

I'm trying to figure out if this matrix operation is possible:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&7\end{bmatrix}\times\begin{bmatrix}1\\5\end{bmatrix}$$

I know that in order to do that I need to find the dimensions of each matrix. How would I do that? What are the dimensions?

Answer (score 4):

The dimension of each matrix is just how many numbers it has down and across, respectively. So your first matrix has dimension $2\times 2$ because it has the form $\pmatrix{*&*\\*&*}$ -- it doesn't matter what the four numbers in it is, just that they are arranged in this shape -- and the second matrix has dimension $2\times 1$ because it has the form $\pmatrix{*\\*}$.

Because the *second* dimension of the *first* matrix is the same as the *first* dimension of the *second* matrix, they can be multiplied.

Comment: Thanks @henning-makholm it took me today to finally figure out the dimension of a matrice... Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If the size of  first factor is $m\times p$ and the second is $p\times n$, the size of the product is $m\times n$.

Answer (score 0):

### Conformable matrices

Two matrices must be *conformable* if they are to be multiplied. Their dimensions must be compatible. For example,
$$
 \mathbf{AB} = \mathbf{C}
$$
we must have
$$
 \mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times \color{red}{n}}, \qquad  \mathbf{B}\in \mathbb{C}^{\color{red}{n}\times p}
$$
The number of *columns* in $\mathbf{A}$ must match the number of *rows* in 
$\mathbf{B}$. The resulting matrix looses knowledge of the dimension $n$, and 
$$
\mathbf{C} \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times p}
$$

Think of it this way: if $\mathbf{A}$ is mom, and $\mathbf{B}$ is dad, the child matrix $\mathbf{C}$ has mom's height and dad's width.

### Dot products

We can see the need for conformability we looking at matrices as a collection of vectors. The matrix on the left, $\mathbf{A}$, has $m$ row vectors of length $\color{red}{n}$; the matrix on the right, $\mathbf{B}$, has $p$ column vectors of length $\color{red}{n}$

$$
\mathbf{A} = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 r^{T}_{1} \\
 r^{T}_{2} \\
 \vdots \\
 r^{T}_{n} \\
\end{array}
\right),
\qquad
\mathbf{B} = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 c_{1} &
 c_{2} &
 \dots &
 c_{n} 
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The matrix product is expressed in terms of dot products:
$$
\mathbf{AB} = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 r^{T}_1 c_{1} & r^{T}_1 c_{2} & \dots  & r^{T}_1 c_{p} \\
 r^{T}_2 c_{1} & r^{T}_2 c_{2} & \dots  & r^{T}_2 c_{p} \\
  \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
 r^{T}_m c_{1} & r^{T}_m c_{2} & \dots  & r^{T}_m c_{p} \\
\end{array}
\right)
=\mathbf{C}
$$

---

Your example:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 2 \\
 3 & 7 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 5 \\
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \cdot 1 + 2 \cdot 5 \\
 3 \cdot 1 + 7 \cdot 5 \\
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 11 \\
 38 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$